# Large PDFsharp (MigraDoc) PdfDocument to byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have been attempting to save a large PdfDocument into a byte array using various means but always come back to an out of memory exception (file is 200 MB and 2.5K pages).

My initial attempt was to simply use MemoryStream

```
public static byte[] ProcessLargePdfDocument(PdfDocument pdfDocument)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pdfDocument.Save(stream, true);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then I tried adding in some buffering

```
public static byte[] ProcessLargePdfDocument(PdfDocument pdfDocument, long whereToStartReading = 0)
{
    List<byte> byteList = new List<byte>();

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pdfDocument.Save(stream, false);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[megabyte];
        stream.Seek(whereToStartReading, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, megabyte);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            byteList.AddRange(buffer);
            bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, megabyte);
        }
    }

    return byteList.ToArray();
}
```

No matter what I try I get an out of memory exception on the pdfDocument.Save call.  I am able to write it to a file location and to read it back using a buffered FileStream in dev but I'm not able to do this on the production environment due to permissions (yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two tips:

Make sure your process runs as a 64-bit process to allow it to use more than 2 GiB of RAM.

`stream.ToArray()` creates a copy, `stream.GetBuffer()` lets you access the internal buffer of the `MemoryStream`. If the exception occurs after the `Save()` this may make a difference.